# WooCommerce - Adding custom HTML to specific product pages

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, html

I'm trying to add some custom HTML to specific WooCommerce products for my client. I successfully learned to add this custom HTML to all product pages at once (more specifically to their descriptions, overriding short-description.php) but I only need products A, B and C to contain this HTML bit and the rest to stay with the default content. A, B and C are in the same product category. How would you narrow the products, via category or product by product, that will contain this HTML, please?

Comment: check the documentation to add something for a particular posts/pages/category https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the documentation to add something for a particular posts/pages/category 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Comment: It worked by finding which post # is the product page for A, B and C and then using is_single() with the custom HTML for each. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can check woocommerce related conditional tag here -

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

You can try below code. In this code add_action execute only when product have category like men or women.

```
function wp_extracode_for_products()
{
  echo'your code'; 
}

add_action( 'wp', 'remove_product_content' );

function remove_product_content() {

  if ( is_product() && (has_term( 'men', 'product_cat' )|| has_term( 'women', 'product_cat' ) )) {

   add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wp_extracode_for_products', 60);

  }
}
```